# Using Robocopy to search and copy directories using pattern matching

Tags: windows, backup, directory, robocopy

I have tried to find an answer to this but most questions related to robocopy and pattern matching are focused on excluding folders whereas my intention is to include folders.

Assuming i have the following folders.

```
c:\workspace\folder1\subfolder1\workInProgress monthly\*
c:\workspace\folder1\subfolder1\completed monthly\*
c:\workspace\folder1\subfolder1\rejected weekly\*

c:\workspace\folder2\subfolder2\workInProgress yearly\*
c:\workspace\folder2\workInProgress documents daily\*
c:\workspace\folder2\subfolder2\completed monthly\*
c:\workspace\folder2\subfolder21\rejected weekly\*

c:\workspace\folder3\subfolder3\workInProgress weekly\*
c:\workspace\folder3\subfolder3\completed daily\*
c:\workspace\folder3\subfolder3\rejected weekly\*
```

I have a backup script that executes the `ROBOCOPY` command for each directory i want to backup.

```
ROBOCOPY "c:\workspace\folder1\subfolder1\workInProgress monthly" D:\folder1\subfolder1\workInProgress documents /COPYALL /B /SEC /E /MIR /Z /XO /XF *.LCK /R:5 /W:5 /LOG+:dSyncFilesMinimal_%vl%_%tl%.txt /IPG:5
ROBOCOPY "c:\workspace\folder2\subfolder2\workInProgress yearly" D:\folder2\subfolder1\workInProgress documents /COPYALL /B /SEC /E /MIR /Z /XO /XF *.LCK /R:5 /W:5 /LOG+:dSyncFilesMinimal_%vl%_%tl%.txt /IPG:5
ROBOCOPY "c:\workspace\folder2\workInProgress daily" D:\folder2\subfolder1\workInProgress documents /COPYALL /B /SEC /E /MIR /Z /XO /XF *.LCK /R:5 /W:5 /LOG+:dSyncFilesMinimal_%vl%_%tl%.txt /IPG:5
ROBOCOPY "c:\workspace\folder3\subfolder3\workInProgress weekly" D:\folder3\subfolder1\workInProgress documents /COPYALL /B /SEC /E /MIR /Z /XO /XF *.LCK /R:5 /W:5 /LOG+:dSyncFilesMinimal_%vl%_%tl%.txt /IPG:5
```

Everytime a new folder is added I have to update the script to include the new folder. 
How can i use `ROBOCOPY` to search the `workspace` folder to find any directory that contains the string `workInProgress` and copy it to a destination location.

Given that i know that the folder to be copied will have the string `workInProgress` in its name, is it possible to run a single `ROBOCOPY` command to recursively search the `c:\workspace` directory and copy across any directory that matches the patter `*workInProgress*`"

- Only folder with patter *workInProgress*
- The `workInProgress` folders can contain different strings after the string `workInProgress` e.g

  `workInProgress daily`
   `workInprogress unknown`
- There is no known pattern on other folders that do not contain `workInProgress` in their name. Other folders can contain random names.

Comment: You could use other commands to generate the script or parameters to pass to `robocopy` in a loop. Getting the directories is easy enough just using  `dir "c:\workspace\workInProgress*" /s /a:d /b`

Answer (score 2):

An example of a `dir` used in a `FOR` loop with how to change the drive letter when outputting it:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %i IN (`dir /s /a:d /b c:\workspace\workInProgress*`) DO @echo "c:%~pi" "d:%~pi"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would probably work for you.

```
$dirs = GetChildItem -recurse -include "*workinprogress*" | ?{ $_.PsIsContainer }

foreach ($dir in $dirs)
{
ROBOCOPY $dir.FullName D:\folder1\subfolder1\workInProgress documents /COPYALL /B /SEC /E /MIR /Z /XO /XF *.LCK /R:5 /W:5 /LOG+:dSyncFilesMinimal_%vl%_%tl%.txt /IPG:5
}
```